# Get notifications for new releases of source code dependencies

Tags: software-development, version-control, source-code

The software I develop includes code from external repositories like [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) for PHP and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) for JavaScript. Also in use are the [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) and [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) frameworks.

For all these software components new versions are released on their own schedule. I am looking for software that can notify me when a new version is released of a component that is in use in one of our products. This allows us to track new features and know when existing bugs are fixed in code that we not maintain ourselves.

Preferably the list of components to monitor should be taken from the files that define the external dependencies for a product. For PHP that is `composer.json` and for JavaScript `package.json`.

These files are stored in svn, but I can process them and put them in a folder, or combine them in a configuration file if required.

For software not defined in such files it would be useful to be able to add Github repositories to monitor.

Comment: I would love to be able to do the same with all the CDN which I use for my AngularJs. in the meantime, take a look at https://visualping.io which just recently moved from being free to being paid for; you might also want to find something similar, but free. It monitors web pages for changes & emails you. If they publish version numbers, that ought to be enough. Of course, we would prefer to automate it, but who has the time?